# (Clojure) Make a partial function instead of throwing an arity exception with too few arguments?

Tags: syntax, clojure

If you give a function too few arguments, it complains:

```
user=> (map-indexed vector)
ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: core$map-indexed
clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)
```

Suppose I want this do something handy instead, like automagically calling `(partial map-indexed vector)`, and I want this new rule to work with every function without having to rewrite all of them. Is there a way to accomplish that, or is there some good reason it's not possible/not idiomatic?

Comment: How do you want to handle multiple/variable arity?  For example, what happens when I call ((map f v1) v2)?  Since map is variadic, does this result to map being applied to [f v1] or to [f v1 v2]?

Comment: If a function call wouldn't throw an exception currently, it should do what it does currently. Valid calls to a function should be that, rather than this sneaky auto-`partial`ing thing. That would evaluate `(map f v1)`, then try to use that thing as a function on `v2`.

Answer (score 2):

You have answered your own question, `partial` is the way to go. You should explain your use case more so that a better answer can be given.

Besides, `map-indexed` expects a function of arity 2 as the first argument and a collection as the second.

The following returns a function that does what you want (I guess).

`(defn foo [f] (fn [] (map-indexed f vector)))`

**EDIT**

I misunderstood the use of `vector` as was pointed out by amalloy. It's not vector as data but as *function*.

Apart from the use of `fn` as shown above and `partial` as mentioned earlier, perhaps you could create a single-character-name synonym (or a really simple macro)  which would expand to a call to `partial`. If you chose `$`, it would be `($ map-indexed vector)`.

Comment: No, he clearly meant `(map-indexed vector)`. `vector` is a function that accepts two args, and is not a collection.

Comment: I know partial does what I want. I want to accomplish the same thing without having to type out the word 'partial', and just giving the function too few arguments seems like it would be a simple and understandable way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this for any function you define

```
(defn f
  ;; The "real" f
  ([x y z] (whatever-f-does x y z))
  ;; Overloads to "automagically" construct partial applications
  ([x] (partial f x))
  ([x y] (partial f x y)))
```

Of course, this can be abstracted with a macro, but that is the pattern.

I don't know whether this is a good idea.  It's probably not what most Lispers would expect from most functions, but I recon it could be quite useful in some contexts.

There are also some limitations to this approach.  Here are a few I thought of:

1. It's only useful for functions you write, or happen to be written by others who also use that pattern.
2. It introduces ambiguity when multiple arity is involved (i.e., if f is a function of either 2 or 3 arguments, is (f x y) a complete application of f or a partial application?)
3. It can't really handle variable arity either (you run into the same problems with ambiguity).

Perhaps a better approach would be to introduce a different function to do the partial application.  For example:

```
(defn partial-f [& args] (apply partial f args))
```

Of course, you would want to choose a better name than "partial-f".  For instance for map, you might use mapper.  And for map-indexed, perhaps indexed-mapper would make sense.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really what I'm going for. I'm imagining some kind of import or some such that applies this rule to any function call within the program, without having to rewrite all the functions. Perhaps this is a little too magical even for Clojure...

Comment: That might not be impossible, but it would involve reaching into the guts of the current namespace and totally rearranging them.  I have a few other ideas you might like better ... I'll post them when I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

Transducers (will) do exactly this for sequence functions, among other cool things.

See: http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2014/8/6/transducers-are-coming