# Is there any macro to help make a function with one open argument?

Tags: clojure

`(map (fn [x] (func 1 2 x)) [0 1 2])` where `func` takes 3 arguments can be written as `(map #(func 1 2 %) [0 1 2])` for short. Is it possible to make it even more concise? Like in OCaml, `(func 1 2)` itself is a function. I don't need to create a new one and pass it to map.

Comment: possible duplicate of [(Clojure) Make a partial function instead of throwing an arity exception with too few arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721222/clojure-make-a-partial-function-instead-of-throwing-an-arity-exception-with-to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clojure doesn't do auto-currying, so you can't just say `(func 1 2)`, but you can use `partial`:

`(map (partial func 1 2) [0 1 2])`